# Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() always returns 0

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, error-handling

```cs
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr OpenSCManagerW(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, int dwDesiredAccess);

Console.WriteLine("Getting the SCM handle...");

IntPtr SCManagerHandle = OpenSCManagerW(null, "shihihihihi", SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
if (SCManagerHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SCM handle successfully retrieved.");
}
else
{
    string ErrorMessage = "The SCM handle could not be retrieved because ";
    int ErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (ErrorCode == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
    {
        ErrorMessage += "the requested access was denied.";
    }
    else if (ErrorCode == ERROR_DATABASE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
    {
        ErrorMessage += "the target database does not exist.";
    }
    else { ErrorMessage += S_UNKNOWN + ErrorCode; }
    ThrowError(ErrorMessage);
}
```

So I have some code which requires the SCM handle, which I retrieve using the `OpenSCManagerW` function from the winapi. To check for errors, I set `SetLastError` to true and use `Marshal.GetLAstWin32Error()`. I purposefully put in an invalid database to check the error handling, and I expected the get the `ERROR_DATABASE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` error, but no matter what I do, I always get 0 as an error code.

Is there something wrong with my setup here? I can't seem to figure out why it returns 0 as the error code.

I'm not sure if this is related, but up until now I always thought you could check the `SCManagerHandle` against null to see if it is null, but when I do that it always returns a success ("SCM handle successfully retrieved"). If I'm not mistaken, an `IntPtr` is a reference type which points to an int (32 bit or 64 bit based on system). So does that mean `IntPtr.Zero` is a reference to a pointer which is 0 and that null is a pointer that is 0. I kind of always assumed that `DllImport` would convert `IntPtr.Zero` to null for ease of use, but I guess I was wrong.

One more question, if what I just said is true, does that mean `int*` is basically the same thing as `IntPtr` in a 32 bit process. Could I, if I wanted to, replace `static extern IntPtr` with `static extern int*`?

Comment: `IntPtr` is `void*`. It's *a pointer*, without specifying to what. `IntPtr.Zero` is `nullptr`. If `SCManagerHandle != IntPtr.Zero` is always true for you, then the function always succeeds, so no wonder GetLastError returns 0 which means "Operation completed successfully".

Comment: "*If I'm not mistaken, an `IntPtr` is a reference type which points to an int*" - no, you are mistaken. It is a **pointer-sized integer**, not a **pointer to an integer**. Two very different things. `IntPtr` represents a pointer in an integer format. "*So does that mean `IntPtr.Zero` is a reference to a pointer which is 0 and that null is a pointer that is 0.*" `IntPtr.Zero` is a pointer-as-integer with a value of 0.

Comment: The sample gives me a `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`(123) error code. And if I pass `SERVICES_FAILED_DATABASE`("ServicesFailed"), then the error code returns `ERROR_DATABASE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Okay, thank you, but there is one thing I still don't understand: If an IntPtr is a value type, which, when set to zero, is just a null pointer, why is IntPtr.Zero not equivalent to null?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa `IntPtr` represents a native C-style pointer within the .NET environment. So `IntPtr.Zero` *IS* the `IntPtr` version of null for such pointers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If that's the case, why isn't it equivalent to null in c#?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa because `null` is only for *reference* types, like pointers, strings, etc. But `IntPtr` *represents* a pointer but is not *itself* a pointer, it is just an integer value type. You can't apply `null` to value types.